# How can I add query to a old query in Flutter for Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

This is how I am getting the data from the Firebase but I want to implement a Filter system in my app by which the request changes like if I take a data from the user like where price is lower than this and I add it in a string and pass that string into this query and it gives me data according to it.

```
response = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("posts")
          .where('type', isEqualTo: widget.type)
          .where('sellercity', isEqualTo: widget.city)
          .limit(documentLimit)
          .get();
```

For example I add a string name State = ".where('sellercity', isEqualTo: "userdata")" to the query where userdata will be null;
like this

```
.collection("posts")
          .where('type', isEqualTo: widget.type)
            + State +
          .where('sellercity', isEqualTo: widget.city)
```

and it works normally but when the user add something to the userdata and it changes and refreshes the data according to it.

Please tell me how can I do this and is there any tutorial or something for it.

Answer (score 0):

Make the initial value of userdata to null

```
String userdata = null;
```

then pass it in the query like this and it'll not effect the search

```
.where('sellercity', isEqualTo: widget.city)
```

Then you can update the userdata by taking input from the user and can update the query.